# hbernate org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to save()at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSave

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

this is the hibernate dode im getting worried about please help me to solve this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="nse_table")
public class retrainDto implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="company_Id")
    private int companyId;

    @Column(name="company_symbol")
    private String companySymbol;

    // some other columns omitted

}
```

this is the dao part of my hibernate program

```
public class retrainDao {

public Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
Configuration cfg=new Configuration().configure();

SessionFactory sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
Session ses=sf.openSession();
Transaction tx=ses.beginTransaction();

 public void saveRetrain(retrainDto dto) {
    Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
    cfg.configure();
    SessionFactory sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session ses=sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx=ses.beginTransaction();
    retrainDto redto=new retrainDto();
    ses.save(dto);
    tx.commit();
}
public retrainDto update(int primarykey) {
    Session ses=null;
    Transaction tx=null;
    try {
        ses=sf.openSession();
        tx=ses.beginTransaction();
        retrainDto redto=new retrainDto();
        System.out.println("give primary key");

        System.out.println("give company id :");
        redto.setCompanyId(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println("give company symbol");
        redto.setCompanySymbol(sc.next());

        // set other columns

        redto=ses.load(retrainDto.class, new Integer(primarykey));
        System.out.println("data updated succesfully");
        ses.save(redto);
        tx.commit();

    }catch(HibernateException e) {e.printStackTrace();}finally {if(ses!=null)ses.close();}
    return null;
}
public retrainDto readData(int primarykey) {
Session ses=null;
Transaction tx=null;
retrainDto redto=null;

    try {
        ses=sf.openSession();
        tx=ses.beginTransaction();

        System.out.println("confirm data  want to retrieve");
        redto=ses.get(retrainDto.class,sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println(redto);
        tx.commit();
    }catch(HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}finally{if(ses!=null)ses.close();}
    return null;
    }
public retrainDto readbyhql(String name) {
    Session ses=null;
    Transaction tx=null;
    retrainDto redto=null;
    try {
        ses=sf.openSession();
        tx=ses.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("try part");
        String hql="FROM retrainDto WHERE companySymbol=?";
        Query query=ses.createQuery(hql,retrainDto.class);
        query.setParameter(0, name);
        redto=(retrainDto)((org.hibernate.query.Query)query).uniqueResult();
        System.out.println("fetching  data");
        System.out.println(redto);
        tx.commit();
    }catch(HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{if (ses!=null)ses.close();}
    return redto;

}
}



   public class retrainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    retrainDto dto=new retrainDto();
    /*System.out.println("give id :");
    dto.setRetrainId(sc.nextInt());
    System.out.println("give name :");
    dto.setRetrainName(sc.next());
    System.out.println("give percentage :");
    dto.setRetrainPercentage(sc.nextInt());

    System.out.println("created successfully");*/
    retrainDao dao=new retrainDao();
    /*dao.saveRetrain(dto);
    System.out.println("saved successfully");*/
    System.out.println("update id please");
    dao.update(sc.nextInt());
    /*System.out.println("give data to read :");
    dao.readData(sc.nextInt());*/
    /*System.out.println("sql by reading is started please enter the                 symbol :");
    dao.readbyhql(sc.next());
    System.out.println("completed reading");*/
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property    name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306    /sehm5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>     
    <mapping class="com.application.retrain.dto.retrainDto"></mapping>

      </session-factory>
   </hibernate-configuration>
```

I really so confused to get solution for this i searched everywhere bt i didnt got solution can any one please clear me where i went wrong and what i have to modify to work it 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can **update** only managed entities. In order to get managed entity you must first attach it to hibernate session by fetching entity by ID. In your `update(int primaryKey)` method you should move your code up:

```
redto=ses.get(retrainDto.class, new Integer(primarykey));
```

and place instead of

```
retrainDto redto=new retrainDto();
```

P.S. if you want to **create new** entity instead of updating existing one, you must **not** manually assign ID property (`redto.setCompanyId(sc.nextInt());`) for a constructed instance, because the Database will do it for you